# Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install

Tags: android, flutter

I'm receiving the following error while running `flutter run` on some projects, however, on other projects it works fine:

```
(base) Nusraths-MacBook-Pro:flutter_uber_clone rahama$ flutter emulators --launch Pixel_2_XL_API_28
(base) Nusraths-MacBook-Pro:flutter_uber_clone rahama$ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing Gradle...                                              0.8s
Resolving dependencies...                                           1.4s
Running Gradle task 'assembly debug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembly debug'... Done                         9.3s
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...                         1.9s
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

ADB: failed to install /Users/rahama/development/flutter_uber_clone/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching the application on Android SDK built for x86.
```

It's just the flutter demo project, I haven't made any changes to it.

Comment: In Preferences --> Debugger -->under Java I changed to kill the debug process immediately. it starts working fine.

Comment: In my case, I was setting up my new Samsung S21 device. I installed the driver, enabled debugging, restarted both laptop and the mobile, etc. But still got this error. The problem was solved by just changing the USB port for the cable connection. That's funny because that USB port is 100% operational and good, my old Android device runs fine, when it's connected to that USB port.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flutter had a new update (I think last night), run `flutter upgrade` in the terminal and it should work fine (at least that did it for me).

Docs: 
To update both the Flutter SDK and the packages that your app depends on, use the `flutter upgrade` command from the root of your app (the same directory that contains the pubspec.yaml file)

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading

Answer (score 36):

Actually, the answer lies in the error message of your question:

> `[ADB: failed to install /Users/rahama/development/flutter_uber_clone/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk: Failure` **`[INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]`**`Error launching the application on Android SDK built for x86.]`

Your Emulator is running out of space, clear its cache:

1. Click on AVD Manager
2. Wipe Data (Your Target Device )

[image: How To Wipe Your Device Data]

You are set to go..

Answer (score 7):

Run in terminal

```
$ flutter clean
```

and then

```
$ flutter pub get
```

and then

```
$ flutter packages get
```

then

```
$ flutter run
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I don't have any other apps installed on my emulator, when I install the flutter app, I get the same error.

I found that the storage space of the emulator is indeed not enough. Because when I created the emulator, the default was only 1024M. When I changed the storage space of the emulator to 4096M, the problem was solved.

[image]

Comment: Yea. It work's for me. Increase storage 4096

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it can work by **uninstalling your app** and and all it's data then try again,

another fix is to **send the apk** you are trying to install from `projectname/build/app/outputs/apk` and **to your device and install it and try again**.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was caused by an adb glitch, not a flutter problem.

This was solved by doing a combination of the following, not sure which step fixed it exactly

1. Reset adb server on desktop, macOS in mycase: `adb kill-server`, and then `adb start-server`
2. Reset USB debugging on the mobile device.
3. Restarted the device.

None of the existing answers worked for me, so it wasn't a flutter problem. A plain `adb install any.apk` didn't work. So I narrowed it down to an adb/usb issue.

Answer (score 1):

this common problem with the Emulator and all you need to clear the Emulator cache .
in my case it was the solution...

1- open AVD Manger.

2- click on the (bottom arrow) that beside (Edit) button.

3- choose Wipe Data.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who arent using a flutter app or android studio here is my solution:
I am using adb commands on my cmd but since I was not able to install on my phone I downloaded an emulator and in my case I am using an emulator called **MEmu** and there it has an option on the sidelines which allows you to install the apk file with a GUI. *Click on The third icon from the right to do* so.
[image: The third icon from the right]

This is the unconventional method I used to install a dummy app.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Following is answer for `stuck at Performing Streamed Install` by `adb install xxx.apk`:

#### phenomenon

use `adb install xxx.apk` and showing `Performing Streamed Install` but stuck, hang forever.

#### Have tried

- re-plug USB cable
- change USB adapter
- change USB cable
- reboot PC(Mac)
- reboot android phone
- restart VSCode
- make adb command shorter

  - from: `adb -s hxxxxxxxxs install -r /Users/limao/dev/xxx/crawler/appAutoCrawler/AppCrawler/task/20201202_xxx_0192LeiMoChuanShuo/20201202_xxx_0192LeiMoChuanShuo_gameApp_Android/20201202_xxx_0192LeiMoChuanShuo_gameApp_Android_0.apk`
  - to: `adb -s hxxxxxxxxs install -r /var/folders/gt/5868sbcd1jq4rxvryqhy2_1sz8n0s3/T/tmpq3ypjfgd/20201202_xxx_0192LeiMoChuanShuo_gameApp_Android_0.apk`
- tried `adb shell pm install` but not support
- etc...

all not work.

#### Final solution

update (original old version `29.0.5`) `adb` to latest version (`30.0.5`)

---

#### Q: how to update adb to latest version

#### A:

- goto

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

to download your platform adb

- 下载适用于 Windows 的 SDK Platform-Tools
- 下载适用于 Mac 的 SDK Platform-Tools
- 下载适用于 Linux 的 SDK Platform-Tools

or:

goto

https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads/

to download:

- windows

  - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip
- Mac

  - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-darwin.zip
- Linux

  - https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip

unzip to got folder `platform-tools`

add the folder to your `PATH` variable

eg:

```sh
vi ~/.zshrc

PATH=/Users/limao/dev/tools/android/adb/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was resolved by updating android studio and all the flutter and dart plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File>> invalidate caches

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a physical device connected via wifi, then I figured out what was wrong. The battery of my device was below 15%, it worked as expected after charging. So, keep an eye on the battery status if you're working with a physical device via wifi.

Answer (score 0):

**By this way I resolved this issues on BlueStack**.***Do these steps for running android applications on BlueStack Emulator.***

```
Go to setting of BlueStack Emulator

Then click on Advance and then
Turn on Android Debug Bridge (ADB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same problem on a physical device, tried all solution i could see out there but none worked.

What worked at the end of the day was to ensure my device API version was also installed in the android studio.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdRi9.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Uj5.png)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31128156)

Answer (score 0):

### Forewords

This question gets the first result from Google, so my answer covers a bit different error.

The error in question has `[INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]` code. My answer is for any `Performing Streamed Install` error that does not specifically define `[INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]` code.

### My Environment

- KDE Neon 5.24 (a.k.a. Ubuntu 20.04 but latest KDE stuff)
- Visual Studio Code from Snap (I use this mainly)
- Android Studio from Snap (I use this to install SDK, Platform Tools and Build Tools)

### Troubleshooting

The problem is this globally installed `/usr/bin/adb` overrides the `adb` that Flutter uses. As you know, Ubuntu has many outdated packages (to protect their system's stability). ADB is one of them. So, if you try to do:

```sh
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

You will highly likely get an output similar to below:

```
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /tmp/adb.1000.log
Server had pid: 12668
--- adb starting (pid 12668) ---
adb I 03-26 03:19:35 12668 12668 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 03-26 03:19:35 12668 12668 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2
adb I 03-26 03:19:35 12668 12668 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 03-26 03:19:35 12668 12668 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 03-26 03:19:35 12668 12668 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 03-26 03:19:35 12668 12668 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/home/erayerdin/.android/adbkey'...
adb I 03-26 03:19:35 12668 12668 adb_auth_host.cpp:391] adb_auth_inotify_init...
adb I 03-26 03:19:35 12668 12668 adb_auth_host.cpp:467] Calling send_auth_response
adb server killed by remote request

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

In some `flutter run` sessions, I've got an output similar to "adb server version (whatever) does not match the client (whatever); killing". That's when I had the doubt maybe I have installed `adb` globally. Check this:

```sh
which adb
# /usr/bin/adb
# This is a sign that this adb might be globally installed.
# This must be a symlink. Just to make sure, I do the following...

realpath /usr/bin/adb
# /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools
# This is the evidence that it has been installed globally.
```

So, we use an outdated version of `adb`, which does not match the target device's adb server.

### Solution

So, we need to get rid of this global `adb` first.

> ⚠ Warning
>
> If you use `adb` from terminal, what we are going to do will remove it. You can add your `{SDK PATH}/platform-tools` where `SDK PATH` is where you have installed SDK to get it back.

Simply do:

```sh
sudo apt remove android-sdk android-sdk-common android-sdk-build-tools android-sdk-build-tools-common android-sdk-platform-tools android-sdk-platform-tools-common
```

However, doing these actually does not remove `adb` from the system. It still lays there for some reason, so, for the last step, we do:

```sh
# simply backup our symlink
sudo mv /usr/bin/adb /usr/bin/adb.bak

# and backup global android-sdk tools
sudo mv /usr/lib/android-sdk /usr/lib/android-sdk.bak
```

After these steps, you can restart your editor and try again. If you want to make double sure, you can optionally do (while your editor's closed):

```sh
# clean the build artifacts
flutter clean

# reinstall the packages because we have cleared them
flutter pub get
flutter pub get packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 12 requires you to add a piece of code to your main activity

Go to your project folder and open the AndroidManifest.xml file

Add the below code in the activity

android:exported="true"

Comment: Android 12 require you to add a piece of code to your main activity

Go to your project folder and open AndroidManifest.xml file

Add the below code in activity

android:exported="true"

Example

<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:exported="true"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme">
 </activity>

Answer (score 0):

I used BlueStacks Emulator and got this error. Nothing from the above worked for me.
Finally I enable the "Android Debug Bridge(ADB)" item in Bluestacks Setting and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've been trying those answers in this page but none of them worked. I spend 3 hours to figure it out why I got this error when I try to run it on real device. Finally it worked when I changed USB port.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved my this issue:

1. I ran the command `flutter clean` to clean the project
2. I deleted the cache of my Samsung mobile device
3. I changed the USB port to establish connection
4. I ran the command `flutter pub get` to fetch the dependencies
5. Finally,I ran the command `flutter run` to compile and run the Flutter
   application on the Samsung mobile device.

By following these steps, I was able to resolve the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i had this error because of the storage my physical device, so try to clean your phone the do the following comands:
`flutter clean`
`flutter upgrade`
`flutter run`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in my case i opened Android studio, Tools> SDK manager> Android SDK> SDK Tools[!
and uninstalled and reinstalled Android SDK Platform-Tools
[image]