# Performing Streamed Install adb: failed to install [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my application for the first time on a real device and found this error

```
 Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
 Performing Streamed Install

 adb: failed to install S:\Work\egy_servy_client_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: 
 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
 Error launching application on PRA LA1.
```

Anyone can help ?

Comment: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE means your device don't have enough storage to install the apk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000915/error-adb-exited-with-exit-code-1-performing-streamed-install)

Comment: I have the same issue with a freshly made emulator using SDK 33

Answer (score 4):

My emulator was freshly created, and I still ran into this issue. So in case you are using the Android SDK 33 for your emulator make sure to adjust the storage. You can do that by:

- Open Device Manager (AVD)
- Edit your Emulator by clicking on the edit button right next to it or creating a new Emulator
- Enable "Show Advanced Settings"
- Scroll down to "Internal Storage" and change it to 1000

Answer (score 2):

Try to wipe your emulators data,

1. Open android studio
2. Tools
3. Device Manager (AVD)
4. A list of your emulators will pop up, locate the one you have a problem with
5. Press the dropdown icon
6. Select **Wipe data** then Okay
7. Start the emulator and then try again

**Note**: the emulator must be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Check your device storage and make free space.

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty obvious, but you don't have enough space on your phone, try deleting some app, or maybe delete some videos.
(Note, at least 100mb are required for a basic flutter debug app)