# Why ADB exited with exit code 1 when failed to install in xiaomi phone?

Tags: android, flutter, debugging, adb, xiaomi

I'm trying to solve an issue; however, it still not working and I'm getting the same error.

> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install
>
> "adb: failed to install
> C:\Users\faruq\AndroidStudioProjects\foodcourtapp\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk:
> Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during
> installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1969704279.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML
> file line #39): com.example.foodcourtapp.MainActivity: Targeting S+
> (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for
> android:exported be defined when intent filters are present] Error
> launching application on M2007J3SG.

I got this problem after the latest update.

I had read the following article: [Error ADB Exited with Exit Code 1 Performing Streamed Install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000915/error-adb-exited-with-exit-code-1-performing-streamed-install), in hopes for an answer but no luck.

I hope  someone could give me an answer, thanks.

Comment: share your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: add this line  android:exported="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml file under android:name=".MainActivity"

Comment: i add that and run, got the request to install the app, but the screen is blank, and this the error: 
'E/flutter (30940): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid SDK hash.
E/flutter (30940): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(143)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter (30940): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(382)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (30940): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(600)] Could not launch engine with configuration.'